# C# LINQ query Select projection, Function programming

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Factory
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public List<OrganizationUnit> Units;
}

public class OrganizationUnit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool ?IsActive { get; set; }
}

public static  class LocalisationRepo  
{
    public static List<Factory> GetFactories()
    {
        List<Factory> fa = new List<Factory>();
        Factory factory = new Factory() { Number="F10", Units = new List<OrganizationUnit> { 
            new OrganizationUnit() 
            { Id = "001", Name = "Quality", IsActive = false}, 
            new OrganizationUnit() { Id = "002", Name = "Line 3", IsActive=null } ,
            new OrganizationUnit { Id="003", Name="IT", IsActive=true } } };

                  Factory factory2 = new Factory()
            {
                Number = "F11",
                Units = new List<OrganizationUnit> {
                new OrganizationUnit()
                { Id = "001", Name = "Quality", IsActive = true},
                new OrganizationUnit() { Id = "002", Name = "Line 3", IsActive=true } ,
                new OrganizationUnit { Id="003", Name="IT", IsActive=true } }
            };

            fa.Add(factory);
            fa.Add(factory2);
        
        return fa;
    }

}
```

There is a linq Query

```
var factories = LocalisationRepo.GetFactories();

var fa = factories.SelectMany(f => f.Units.Where(u => (u.IsActive ?? false) == false), (f, u) => f).Distinct();

foreach (var item in fa)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Number);
}
```

The first part `f => f.Units.Where(u => (u.IsActive ?? false) == false)`
gives us `IEnumerable<OrganizationUnit>`
the second parameter `(f, u) => f` (A transform function to apply to each element of the intermediate sequence)
"projects each element of sequence to `IEnumerable<Out T>`"

My question is how transition from `IEnumerable<OrganizationUnit>` to `IEnumerable<Factory>` is made by this selector/delegate when at "output" from first argument is `IEnumerable<OrganizationUnit>`
How should it be considered / understood?

We know that f is a Factory, but "intermediate result" is OrganizationUnit so ... HOW ? Some theory about function programming?

I want factories with inactive OrganisationUnits  IsActive=false;
But I'm not asking about how to fint result because my example works fine.
I would like to know how it works, and why...

The same as in Microsoft example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-6.0

We can make query
var query =
petOwners
.SelectMany(po => po.Pets.Where(p => p.StartsWith("S")), (po, p) => po);

Comment: What are you trying to do in the end? I don't think you're using `SelectMany` in the way that you think. Are you trying to project to a new list of factories, taking only the units with them that are active?

Comment: Factory method should be `Func<TInput, TOutput>`. From what I'm seeing I even do not understand what you are trying to achieve. How `OrganizationUnit` should be translated to `Factory` class?

Comment: I modified example. So you can check now, It will be clearer
I want factories with inactive OrganisationUnits  IsActive=false;
But I;m not asking about how to fint result because my example works fine.
I would like to know how it works, and why...

Comment: "my example works fine" are you sure? Is all you want the IDs of factories that have a unit that matches the condition, or are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusion here is related to the (unnecessary) use of `SelectMany` to filter the factories.

In this statement:

```
var fa = factories.SelectMany(f => f.Units.Where(u => (u.IsActive ?? false) == false), (f, u) => f);
```

The `(f, u) => f` parameter is basically ignoring what selectmany picks (which is `u`), and picking the original factory `f` anyways.

<s>So in the end, your statement is equivalent to:
```
var fa = factories.Select(f => f);
```
Which is basically a no-op.</s>

So the above is not exactly the case. It turns out, that your actual query is equivalent to

```
var fa = factories.Where(f => f.Units.Any(u => (u.IsActive ?? false) == false);
```

This is because, for every factory, that `SelectMany` overload will pick each of the matching `Unit`s you provided, hand it to you as the func parameters on the third argument, and wait for you to then transform it to whatever you want. So it expects you to transform a `(Factory,Unit)` pair into `some T`. You decided to avoid the transformation and instead pick the first element, the `Factory` f. Then, `SelectMany` will combine the result of all such lambda executions into a final sequence, in your case, containing factories only. If any factory in your list contains more than one disabled unit, it will appear multiple times in the final result, which is why you had to add a `Distinct` to it for the query "to make sense".

If you want to filter for "factories with at least one inactive unit", you'd do something like this instead:

```
var fa = factories.Where(f => f.Units.Any(u => (u.IsActive ?? false) == false);
```

And if you want "factories whose units are all inactive", you'd do this:

```
var fa = factories.Where(f => f.Units.All(u => (u.IsActive ?? false) == false);
```

> We know that f is a Factory, but "intermediate result" is OrganizationUnit so ... HOW ? Some theory about function programming?

The "intermediate result" is *not* `OrganizationUnit`: with this overload, the intermediate result is actualy a `(Factory,OrganizationResult)` pair, which *you* are "transforming" to just `Factory` by picking `f` as the result. There is nothing special about it.

`SelectMany` should be used for flattening results, which you don't seem to need.

Comment: @Artur Can you show exactly how my query doesn't work? Are you sure you are using `Where` and not `Select`? `Where` doesn't alter the return type, so it will remain `IEnumerable<Factory>` which is what your original `factories` is.

Comment: Without SelectMany and (f, u) => f) in my query you will get IEnumerabe<IEnumerable<OrganisationUnit>> (list with IsActive=false) So SelectMany "flattens" that. 
Your query works fine, but I wantted to know how my is working

Comment: @Artur ok, I see you edited now. Does my explanation make sense to you? Basically, you are getting to the same result in a very roundabout manner. It works, but it not the cleanest way to achieve the result you desire.

Comment: thanks, I know more now  ;) 

`var fa = factories.SelectMany(f => f.Units.Where(u => (u.IsActive ?? false) == false), (f, u) => new
            {
                FactoryName = f.Number,
                OuId = u.Id,
                OuName = u.Name,
                IsActive = u.IsActive
            });`

Answer (score 1):

SelectMany operator used to select the elements from collection of collection called Nested Collection.

SelectMany returns a single result from a nested collection
You can use SelectMany to get every OrganizationUnit line from the factory.

`var fa = factories.SelectMany(f => f.Units.Where(u => !(u.IsActive??false)), (factory, unit) => unit);`

You are trying to in the reverse direction.

**Important** do not use .Distinct() to fix the duplicates. The duplicates should not be there in the first place.

**Solution:**

`var fa = factories.Where( factory => factory.Units.Any(unit => (unit.IsActive?? false) == false));`

Answer (score 1):

> How should it be considered / understood?

You're doing a SelectMany on a list of Factories and you're telling SM you want it to flatten the Units in each Factory. The second argument represents a function that takes both the current Factory being iterated and one of the Units being iterated.

```
listOfFactories.SelectMany(aFactory => aFactory.listOfTheUnits, (theCurrentFactory, oneOfTheUnitsOfTheCurrentFactory) => ...)
```

Or in non delegate terms

```
listOfFactories.SelectMany(GetUnitsFromAFactory, DoSomethingWithAFactoryAndUnitAndGetAnOutput)
```

A SelectMany is conceptually just a nested pair of foreach loops; in those terms it might be like:

```
var output = List<SomeOutput>();

foreach(var aFactory in listOfFactories){
  var theCurrentFactory = aFactory;
  var someEnumerable = GetUnitsFromAFactory();

  foreach(var oneOfTheUnitsOfTheCurrentFactory in someEnumerable){
    output.Add(DoSomethingWithAFactoryAndUnitAndGetAnOutput(theCurrentFactory, oneOfTheUnitsOfTheCurrentFactory);
  }
}

//methods 
IEnumerable<OrganizationUnit> GetUnitsFromAFactory(Factory f){
  return f.listOfTheUnits;
}

SomeOutput DoSomethingWithAFactoryAndUnitAndGetAnOutput(Factory f, Unit u) {
  ...
}
```

The confusing thing with your code is that you only return the factory from the "DoSomethingWithAFactoryAndUnitAndGetAnOutput", so if you had 3 factories with 10, 11 and 12 units respectively you'd end up with a list of 33 factories, 10 repeats of the first factory, 11 repeats of the second and 12 repeats of the third. Now we're (hopefully) happy that SelectMany is a nested loop pair, let's add in the other bit about the units being inactive

```
var out = new List<Factory>
foreach(var f in factories)
  foreach(var u in f.Units)
    if(unit.IsActive ?? false == false)
      out.Add(f);
```

You see, you've added a factory multiple times, once for every inactive unit it has

You then Distinct these to collapse them so the whole SelectMany was something of a wasted exercise and you could instead just ask for the factories with inactive units. In simple loop terms that might look like:

```
var out = new List<Factory>
foreach(var f in factories)
  foreach(var u in f.Units)
    if(unit.IsActive ?? false == false){
      out.Add(f);
      break;
    }
```

Adding the break in stops after adding a single factory (encountering the first inactive unit). In progressively-adding-LINQ terms that's more like doing

```
foreach(var f in factories)
  if(f.Units.Any(unit => unit.IsActive ?? false == false))
    out.Add(f);
```

Which is

```
factories.Where(f => f.Units.Any(unit => unit.IsActive ?? false == false))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `SelectMany` is doing what you think it is doing. I think you think that it's returning the factories with the units filtered to only those where `IsActive` is `false` by some sort of projection from a collection of units back to a factory. That is not correct.

The second selector to `SelectMany` is the `resultSelector` in which you pass:

```
 (f, u) => f
```

Where `f` and `u` are the items of the source collection, and the items of the collection projected by the previous parameter (your `Where` result). What that means is that for any unit that meets the `Where` condition (`u`), it returns *the factory that contains it* (`f`). That's why you have to call `Distinct`, because you're actually getting the factory *for every matching unit*. If a factory has two units that meet the criteria, you're getting the same factory back twice. `Unique` removes those duplicate factories from the result, but the factories themselves (meaning the connections of units within them) are not changed.

In order to "filter" the sub-collection, you'd need to re-project the factories:

```
var fa = factories.Select(f => new Factory(
        {
          Number = f.Number, 
          Units = f.Units.Where(u => (u.IsActive ?? false) == false).ToList();
        }
      )
    );
```

or, alternately, loop though the factories and *remove* the units where `IsActive` is `true`.

Comment: It was a part of excercise about "Select in linq"  Thanks.

Comment: Okay, well hopefully that shows you what the second selector is doing - there's no magic or "functional" trickery involved.